# Distinguish between inner and outer boundary in MeshRegion

Tags: regions, finite-element-method, mesh

For example, this is a 2D `MeshRegion` with one (or more) holes in it:

```
mr = DiscretizeRegion@RegionDifference[
   Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}],
   Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5]
]
```

I would like to identify outer boundary (`MeshCells`) and inner boundary of a hole. I can get indices of all boundary `MeshCells`, but cannot distinguish between them. How can I do that?

```
HighlightMesh[mr, MeshCellIndex[mr, {1, "Boundary"}]]
```

[image: mesh]

Ultimately I will convert this `MeshRegion` to `ElementMesh` and assign different integer markers to `LineElement`s on the boundary.

Comment: What is the reason you start with a MeshRegion in the first place?

Comment: @user21 There is no particular reason, I just couldn't think of a better solution. Actually the input and output for this procedure will always be `ElementMesh`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ConnectedMeshComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedMeshComponents.html) as follows:

```
cmc = ConnectedMeshComponents[DiscretizeGraphics[MeshPrimitives[mr, {1, "Boundary"}]]]; 

Show[mr,  Epilog -> Thread[{Thickness[.01], {Red, Blue},  MeshPrimitives[#, 1] & /@ cmc}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your `MeshRegion` to a boundary element mesh with auto generated markers by:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary[mr]];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> "BoundaryGrouping"]]
```

[image]

The fact that the rectangle has also been split is desirable for FEM. You can look at the markers generated.

```
bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Here is a mesh that has an outer boundary, an inner boundary and a material boundary:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[(x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 >= (1/
        2)^2 && (x + 1/2)^2 + (y + 1/2)^2 >= (1/2)^2, {{x, -2, 
     2}, {y, -2, 2}}];
(mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], 
    "RegionHoles" -> {{-1/2, -1/2}}, 
    "RegionMarker" -> {{{1/2, 1/2}, 2}, {{1/2, -1/2}, 1}}, 
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.125])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

You can then extract the boundary element marker union; these markers are auto generated.

```
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Some colors for the markers:

```
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp
```

[image]

```
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[#] & /@ colors)]]
```

[image]

To further work with this you could use `MeshElementSplitByMarker`:

```
mesbm = Flatten[
   MeshElementSplitByMarker[
    MeshOrderAlteration[mesh, 1]["BoundaryElements"]]];
```

and extract one of the components:

```
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[mesh["Coordinates"], 
  Line[ElementIncidents[mesbm[[6]]]]]]
```

[image]

This selection works by looking at normals and grouping them with some threshold. There are a few examples in the ElementMesh ref page in the Scope section under "BoundaryNormals".

Another approach is to use the "VertexBoundaryConnectivity" in conjunction with `StronglyConnectedComponents`.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];
belems = bmesh["BoundaryElements"];

bincidents = Join @@ ElementIncidents[belems];
S = bmesh["VertexBoundaryConnectivity"];
S = Transpose[S].S;
components = SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[S];
pls = Map[Line[Developer`ToPackedArray /@ (Part[bincidents, #])] &, 
  components]
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[bmesh["Coordinates"], pls]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think that `StronglyConnectedComponents` method is suitable for me, since my `ElementMesh` objects may come without distinct markers of `"BoundaryElements"`, because they could be imported from elsewhere.

Comment: @Pinti, I think they should have boundary markers even if they are imported. If not, could you please send me such an example to look at it? Thanks.

Comment: Very useful! Which version did you use? In MMA 11.0 on Windows, the third line of your reply (`bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> "BoundaryGrouping"]]`) throws an error: `BoundaryGrouping is not a Graphics primitive or directive.`

Comment: Reproduced on another 11.0 Windows machine. Works fine in 11.3.